# Tadpole cancellation condition for $C_4$ in Type IIB Supergravity theory

Tags: string-theory, supergravity, string-theory-landscape

In the following I use Polchinski's notation.

Type IIB Supergravity action (with non-vanishing fluxes & $\rm{D3}$-branes) contains 
\begin{align}
S_{\mathrm{IIB}} &= S_{\mathrm{NS}} + S_{\mathrm{R}} + S_{\mathrm{CS}} + S_{\mathrm{local}} \\&\supset - \frac{1}{4} \int d^{10}x \frac{1}{2} |\tilde{F}_5|^2 + \frac{1}{8i \rm{Im} S} \int C_4 \wedge G_3 \wedge \bar{G_3} + \frac{1}{2} \left(N_{\rm{D3}} - \frac{1}{2} N_{\rm{O3}}\right) \mu_3 \int_{\mathbb{R}^{1,3}}C_4\\
&=-\frac{1}{8}\int \tilde{F}_5 \wedge \star \tilde{F}_5 + \frac{1}{8i \rm{Im} S} \int C_4 \wedge G_3 \wedge \bar{G_3} + \frac{1}{2} \left(N_{\rm{D3}} - \frac{1}{2} N_{\rm{O3}}\right) \mu_3 \int_{\mathbb{R}^{1,3}}C_4,
\end{align}
where $G_3 = F_3 - S H_3$ with $F_3 = dC_2, H_3 = dB_2$ and $S$ denotes complex dilaton. 
$\tilde{F}_5$ is not $dC_4$ but $\tilde{F}_5 = dC_4 - \frac{1}{2} C_2 \wedge H_3 + \frac{1}{2} B_2 \wedge F_3$. Then the Bianchi identity for $\tilde{F}_5$ is corrected from usual one:
\begin{equation}
 d \tilde{F}_5 = H_3 \wedge F_3.
\end{equation}
This matches equation (12.1.28) on Polchinski's textbook. Furthermore, $\tilde{F}_5$ must be self-dual: $\star\tilde{F}_5 = \tilde{F}_5$. We have to impose this by hand.

The equation of motion of $C_4$ from this action gives a tadpole cancellation condition.
I calculated that and the result is:
\begin{align}
 d \star \tilde{F}_5 = d \tilde{F}_5 = H_3 \wedge F_3 - 2 \left(N_{\rm{D3}} - \frac{1}{2} N_{\rm{O3}}\right)  \mu_3 \delta(\mathbb{R}^{1,3})
\end{align}
where $\delta(\mathbb{R}^{1,3})$ is the Poincaré dual of $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$. This matches (except for local term) equation (12.1.28) on Polchinski's textbook again so I guess it's correct.

However, I am confused since $d \tilde{F}_5 = H_3 \wedge F_3$ will be true still now so if we substitute this into above EOM we get
\begin{align}
0 = - 2 \left(N_{\rm{D3}} - \frac{1}{2} N_{\rm{O3}}\right)  \mu_3 \delta(\mathbb{R}^{1,3}).
\end{align}
Actually, this must be incorrect. In fact, [a famous paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0105097.pdf) says

> The
>   integrated Bianchi identity 
>   \begin{align}
> \frac{1}{2 \kappa_{10}^{2} T_{3}} \int_{\mathcal{M}_{6}} H_{(3)} \wedge F_{(3)}+Q_{3}^{\mathrm{loc}}=0
> \end{align}

and I can't understand it ($Q_3^{\rm{loc}}$ is local obj.'s charge).

My Question is:

**(1) What does "the integrated Bianchi identity" mean?**

**(2) How can I get the correct expression?**

**(3) Is my above calculation wrong?**

Sorry for taking your time. Thank you very much.

### **Updates**

- Maybe $d \tilde{F}_5 = H_3 \wedge F_3$ is invalid when we add local source term like above. A textbook says because of self-duality, EOM and bianchi id. of $\tilde{F}_5$ become same (why?). However, I don't understand why the expression $d\tilde{F}_5$ is modified.
- I wonder if the integration of $d\tilde{F}_5$ on the bulk (6d CY $X$) equals to zero. Is it a reasonable assumption?:
  \begin{align}
   \int_{X} d\tilde{F}_5 = \int_{\partial X} \tilde{F}_5 \stackrel{?}{=} 0
  \end{align}

Comment: maybe you could try this site  which is mainly theoretical https://www.physicsoverflow.org/

Comment: For the later reference, this question was just forgetting the Stokes theorem is cannot adopted on the surface with a singularity.