# Field Strength and Source terms

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

This question is related to my recent unanswered [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/532675), but it was too complicated so please let me make this new question at first.

First, I consider a field strength which is expressed as 
\begin{align}
F = dA
\end{align} 
with $A$ ($A$ is some differential form). It is just a generalization of usual Maxwell theory.

The Bianchi identity is clearly 
\begin{align}
 dF = 0.
\end{align}

Now consider the action is given as

\begin{align}
 S = \int F \wedge \star F.
\end{align}

Then EOM for $F$ is

\begin{align}
 d\star F = 0,
\end{align}

It's OK.  Next, I consider an additional source term for $S$ s.t.
\begin{align}
S = \int F \wedge \star F - q \int A \wedge \delta.
\end{align}
Here $\delta$ is just a Poincaré dual, which depends on where $A$ lives.

Then EOM becomes

\begin{align}
d\star F = q \delta,
\end{align} 
It's OK again.

Then, please consider the case $F$ is self-dual i.e. $F = \star F$.

Now $dF=0$ from Bianchi, which contradicts the EOM unless $q=0$.

I know when we write $F=dA$ automatically source terms like magnetic monopole vanishes, but how can I solve this contradiction?

I think I should re-define $F$ to match its EOM, but the action with source term don't tell me to do so I think.

Please help me.

Answer (score -1):

If $F$ is self dual
$$
\begin{align}
F = \star F
\end{align}
$$
The action 
\begin{align}
S = \int F \wedge \star F = \int F \wedge  F
\end{align}
turns into a topological Pontryagin term, where EOM does NOT apply.

You should be talking about its Chern class instead.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with a topological Pontryagin term, but in string theory (IIB SUGRA) there is a self-dual 5-form $\tilde{F}_5$ and several textbooks say if we consider EOM for $\tilde{F}_5$ we can get Bianchi identity and above my question is a sketch of that discussion.  
Please tell me what does "where EOM does NOT apply" mean. We cannot get EOM from this action?

Comment: @Keyspire, my answer is based on 4D. What is your action for the 5-form $\tilde{F}_5$ and what's the dimension, and is the gauge group Abelian?

Comment: oh I thought my question does not depend on dimension too much but it's not...

I consider 10D action in fact. and gauge group is Abelian I think, hence $F_5\wedge \star F_5$ is actually zero. This my old question (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/532675/tadpole-cancellation-condition-for-c-4-in-type-iib-supergravity-theory) has some detail.